# Can I hide an icon on a Ribbon for particular users?

Tags: c#, excel, ribbon

I want to show an icon on a Ribbon tab for particular users.

like...

```
If username ="Mike"
    hide icon1
else
    show icon1
```

Is there any way to get username who are using Excel workbook in C#?

I can set up password for this icon but if I can get username, it will be easier.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You can get the username from the [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Equals("username"))
{
    button1.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    button1.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Application class from the Excel object model provides the [UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822584(v=office.15).aspx) property. Moreover, you can't set the Visible property directly for Ribbon UI controls. You need to use callbacks (getVisible) and call the IRibbonUI.Invalidete or InvalidateControl methods to get your callbacks invoked. You can read more about the Ribbon UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)